# 2x2 Matrix with real entries and a complex eigenvalue can't be normal

Tags: linear-algebra

Homework question.

---

Let $A$ be a $2 \times 2$ matrix with real entries.  Suppose that $A$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda$ with the imaginary part of $\lambda \neq 0$.  Is there an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{C}_2$ consisting entirely of eigenvectors of $A$?  Explain.

---

So far I've got the following:

A matrix is self-adjoint iff its eigenvalues are all real.  By the spectral theorem, a linear transformation $T$ from $V$ to $V$ is normal iff its eigenvectors span $V$.  A linear transformation is normal iff it commutes with its adjoint.

With these three facts, I can state that A is not self-adjoint, and I need to show that it is not normal, assuming that the proposition is false (my belief).

I've found a couple simple counterexamples, but I can't figure out how to make the jump from not self-adjoint to not-normal.  (Or any other method of showing it's not normal).

Comment: What about $$\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$$?

Comment: There exist normal examples. Take a rotation matrix. (Its adjoint is its inverse.)

Comment: ...and the example I gave is in fact both a rotation matrix and a skew-symmetric matrix.

Comment: And the eigenvectors I get are (i,1) and (-i,1), which are orthogonal.  Hm, I was wrong then.

Comment: Is it not true that the adjoint of a matrix is its conjugate transpose?  I feel I may be missing something.  {{2,3},{-2,1}} doesn't commute with it's conjugate transpose, at least.

Answer (score 3):

A matrix whose entries are real has a characteristic polynomial whose coefficients are all real.  Any non-real eigenvalues must then come in complex-conjugate pairs, and the complex conjugate of an eigenvector $v$ for $\lambda$ must be an eigenvector for $\overline{\lambda}$.
If the matrix $A$ is normal, $v$ and $\overline{v}$ must be orthogonal to each other, 
which says that $v^T v = 0$.  So in the $2 \times 2$ case the eigenvectors must be
of the form $\pmatrix{t\cr \pm i t\cr}$.  If $\lambda = a + i b$ is any non-real complex number, the normal matrix with normalized eigenvectors $\pmatrix{1\cr + i\cr}/\sqrt{2}$ for $\lambda$ and $\pmatrix{1\cr - i\cr}/\sqrt{2}$ for $\overline{\lambda} = a - i b$ is
$$ A = \frac{a + i b}{2} \pmatrix{1\cr i\cr} (1, -i) + \frac{a - i b}{2} \pmatrix{1\cr -i\cr} (1, i) 
= \pmatrix{a & b\cr -b & a\cr}$$